# How to fix a graphical bug in v. 13.0.1?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, arrowhead

How can I fix this graphical issue? My code only plots a basis
reference frame and a rotated reference frame. The arrowhead of
the Z axis is the issue

```
Rz[\[Alpha]_] := ({
{Cos[\[Alpha]], -Sin[\[Alpha]], 0},
{Sin[\[Alpha]], Cos[\[Alpha]], 0},
{0, 0, 1}
});


   X0 = IdentityMatrix[3]
   x0 = Dot[Rz[\[Alpha]], #] &@X0

refframe[PB_, CAB_, arrowLength_] := 
 Map[{Apply[RGBColor, #], Arrowheads[0.1], 
    Arrow[Tube[{PB, PB + arrowLength (CAB . #)}], 0]} &,
    IdentityMatrix[3]]

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{refframe[{0, 0, 0}, X0, 1], 
    refframe[{0.1, 0.1, 0.1}, x0, 0.501]}, Boxed -> False, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1.0}, {-.5, 1.0}, {-.5, 1.0}}] /. \[Alpha] -> 
   a, {a, 0, \[Pi]}]
```

This only happens when the blue arrow points in the direction {0,0,1}

[image: Error when displaying Arrowheads]

By rotating it around any other axis, just so it stops pointing into {0,0,1} produces normal arrowheads, notice the other arrowhead is messed up.

[image: Example 2 arrowheads]